# Haskell - Find and remove element from a list of list

Tags: list, haskell

I need to find an element l in a list of list, removing each list containing the element, and then return the list of list, but i don't know how to parsing list of list and, at the same time, removing the list and keeping parsing the rest of the list.

To be more understandable, i have :

```
data Object = Pos Char | Neg Char
     deriving (Show, Eq)

type Box = [Object]

type Formula = [Box]

findAndDelete :: Formula -> Object -> Formula
findAndDelete cs l
findAndDelete (c:cs) l
```

**edit** : At the same time, I need to remove all x element from the Formula,x is returned by a function named negative with l in parameter.

```
negative :: Object -> Object
negative (Pos v) = Neg v
negative (Neg v) = Pos v
```

Comment: What if the object occurs multiple times?

Comment: I have to remove each occurrence.

Comment: Do you want to remove the object occurrences or the box that contains the object?

Comment: I want to remove the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to remove the `Box` that contains the element you could use `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` to check just that:

```
findAndDelete :: Formula -> Object -> Formula
findAndDelete [] o = []
findAndDelete (b:bs) o = case (elem o b) of {
                            True -> findAndDelete bs o;
                            False -> b:(findAndDelete bs o)
                       };
```

So to remove the negative objects during the `findAndDelete` function you can use `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` this will give you a `Box` where all the objects satisfy the predicate:

```
findAndDelete :: Formula -> Object -> Formula
findAndDelete [] o = []
findAndDelete (b:bs) o = case (elem o b) of {
                             True -> findAndDelete bs o;
                             False -> (filter ((/=) (negative o)) b):(findAndDelete bs o)
                          };
```

Comment: And if I also want to delete another object returneb by another function ? I'm very bad with haskell sorry

Comment: What do you mean by that? If it's related to this just edit the question including more info or create a new one

Comment: Thank, it's more the seconde case but i need to do this inside the function, not when i call the function

Comment: In that case if you change the `case` with `(elem o b) || (elem (negative o) b)` that would be removing the box if it contains the object or it's negative

Comment: But if it contains the negative, i just have to remove the element, not the box, from the formula

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the **boxes**, you can filter for all the boxes who do not have the given object as their element.

```
import Data.List

findAndDelete :: Formula -> Object -> Formula
findAndDelete f o = filter (not . elem o) f
```